# Can any one help to encode the rails code.I want to share my code in binary executable form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to share my rails code with my client in encoded form so he can not able to read the code.Is it possible in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found sth like that: https://www.rubyencoder.com/
Never used it....probably other solutions are available on google

Comment: Please look into the name that is only for ruby code not the rails. I have already gone through the documentation

Comment: Ok i've just checked - you are right. only .rb files will be encoded...